# Is there a way to find the trigger and stored procedure call chain from a given procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-trigger

Where I work there is a complex update sequence that is a pain to try to graph by hand and I was wondering if there was a way to get all triggers and procedures called within a specific stored procedure.

Anything would be fine even if it doesn't graph the results, but that would be preferable. Is there a query, SSMS plugin, or software solution for this?

I've tried searching around, but I was unable to find anything that could do this. Most people talked about the Search from SQL Prompt, but that doesn't really achieve what I need since I have to determine what could be triggered from a procedure.

Comment: Look at [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql) for at least part of that.

Comment: You can use `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` to fetch the execution plan of almost everything that happens in the stored procedure, including dynamic statements -- unfortunately with the exception of triggers, but you could look those up based on the DML operations that happen and whether triggers are defined.

Comment: Or just use profiler while you debug the procedure.

Comment: You can try with extended events.